# Getting just Windows 8 (no dual boot) back from Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, windows-8, data-recovery

My Acer v5 was originally Windows 8 but I loaded Ubuntu 13.04 and I think overwrote the Windows 8 OS. I have tried every way I could find to see if I could locate the Windows 8 or Acer eRecovery management but was unable to find any tiny bit of them. Is there any way to install one of them back and get Windows 8 or do a factory reset that will reset it all the way back to when I got it? I'm not sure if the factory reset will just reset my Ubuntu.

I don't want to dual boot, I just want Windows 8 back, any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Check partitions. Boot your linux live cd/bootable usb, press "ALT+F2", write "gparted", then check how many paritions do you see?

If there are 2 partitions (maybe 3 or 4, because os swap. Windows has as well) - you can recover your windows partition somehow, but if you see only one linux partition and it's swap logical partition, you are mucked up! (Sorry moderators, but what does 'mucked up' mean? o.O )

That means put Windows 8 cd and install it

Comment: There is only the one partition. I have made a bootable usb with Windows 8 on it but it wont allow me to install it. Is this because  of the fact I have ubuntu on already?

Comment: I remember I installed Linux on my PC from my Android device using "DriveDroid". I also tried to install Windows 7 from it - didn't work. Tried from bootable USB - didn't work as well. 


So if you want to install Windows OS I recommend to use DVD disc written 4x speed. (Faster speed will increase chance of it to be corrupted - happened to me twice)

This is just my opinion and I can be wrong, but only CD worked for me. Have a good luck!